# Scoping issue - calling an internal dojo function from external function

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri-javascript-api

I have a function that is outside of the require portion of the dojo functions.

This function needs to call a function that resides within the dojo require block.

How do i call a function that is within the require code block from a function that resides outside the dojo require block?

Perhaps a little more application flow will demonstrate the need

- Main window application spawns a child window
- Main window sends a message to the child window that has a global function that will receive the message
- Child window receives the message
- The external function parses the message and determines that the map
  needs to be updated (The child window that is spawned is the mapping window and loads a lot of ESRI modules in the require section)
- the child window function needs to call a function that is
  within the require code block of dojo to do the actual ESRI related tasks

Comment: posting some portion of code would hel , also , are you using sort of Iframe or , pupup window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk about a hack...   here is what i did to get the results i needed.

I created a hidden button on the form, bound the click event to fire off the function.

When the message was received and processed, I fired off the button click event - and viola!!

thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hacky solution and you should really think of a way to rearrange your modules if possible, but this should at least work:

```
var inside = null;

function outside () {
  try { inside(); }
  catch (err) { /* log error or throw away, whatever */ }
}

require(['dojo/_base/declare', ..., 'your/module/function'], function (declare, ..., myModuleFunction) {
  inside = myModuleFunction;
  outside();
});
```

Just `require` the module which contains the function (named `"your/module/function"` and `myModuleFunction` in the example), store it in a variable *outside* of the require and call it in a function which has been defined *outside* already. I added a `try-catch` block because it is good measure and prevents your code from blowing up if you call `outside` too early.

In case the function *inside* the dojo require block isn't a module, it's almost the same:

```
var inside = null;

function outside () {
  try { inside(); }
  catch (err) { /* log error or throw away, whatever */ }
}

require(['dojo/_base/declare'], function (declare) {
  inside = function () { console.log('Inside the require block'); };
  outside();
});
```

Except that you don't have to `require` it.

Comment: Hi David - thanks for the reply...   the myModuleFunction you described - would you elaborate on this function?

Comment: `myModuleFunction` is just a name which stands for the function _inside your require block_. The only reason I could think of why you cannot reach it without importing/requiring it is because it is a module (or part of a module) itself. Your question doesn't mention any names so I had to come up with something ;-)